# 2 xLM324N lead battery charger fail. Images added

Tags: charger, 12v, lead-acid

i have a Lead Acid battery charger that was given to me since its not working.

I have no 12volts output neither any led on.

Schematics do not appear after hours of google search

So far ive tested diodes/bridges/resistors

I see that resistor R23 is missing (or at least seems) but, which is the value of that resistor?

I cant figure out why the variable resistor works.

The two chips are LM324N sti chips.

[image: back board]

[image: front]

Comment: Forgot to mention, transformer is ok also output 12volts is ok

Comment: The pcb doesn't look to be in good condition. To be specific, check out those resistors to the right of Q2. One seems to be one legged. Also, R23 you mentioned, looks like it's been removed. Sometimes manufacturers leave out components, but clearly not that R23.

Comment: Hi Minime im agree that R23 is not intended to be out, but, do you have a hint of the value it should be?

Comment: I'd categorize the PCB from the images as "junk". It's probably not worth wasting any more time on it.

Comment: Not a clue. This pcb have seen better days, so I'll chime in with Andy.

Comment: The charger is not worth much BUT look "repairable enough". || BTB24 is a TRIAC. What is the other power device? || The circuit is easily enough traceable. || The R23 is in series with the pot track. 
 You could measure the pot value an either use a series variable resistor or say 10 x pot value in R23 position or a range of fixed resistors from 2x to 10x pot full value. || IF the other power device is a bipolar transistor you could asily checl BE and BC junctions. Then ... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Indeed a resistor was loose near q2. Circuit thread was broken at c2 so i finally discarded the circuit and saved the transformer. Thanks for the help, but indeed was a dead from start circuit